# Control select input height within sidebar with R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to increase the height of a select input inside the sidebar of a shinydashboard. When started, the height is correct, but immediatly, the size decrease to the default one.

I try use tags$style :

```
tags$style(type='text/css', "#input_id {height: 100px}")
```

Here is a reproductible example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <-  dashboardPage(
    title = "Plan de gestion",
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "test"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            selectInput(inputId = "test_size", label = "Test", choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
            tags$style(type='text/css', "#choix_param {height: 100px}")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(

    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I find the solution : 
```tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#test_size+ div>.selectize-input {min-height: 500px}")))```

Comment: Great. You should be able to answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution :

`tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#test_size+ div>.selectize-input {min-height: 500px}")))`

Comment: That appears to be the solution. I wonder why this attribute cannot be set within an external .css file?